# Shell: extract words matching pattern, but ignore circumventing expression

Tags: shell, nested, pattern-matching

I am currently trying to extract ALL matching expressions from a text which e.g. looks like this and put them into an array.

```
aaaaaaaaa${bbbbbbb}ccccccc${dddd}eeeee
ssssssssssssssssss${TTTTTT}efhsekfh ej
348653jlk3jß1094utß43t59ßgöelfl,-s-fko
```

The matching expressions are similar to this: `${}`. Beware that I need the full expression, not only the word in between this expression! So in this case the result should be an array which contains:

```
${bbbbbbb}
${dddd}
${TTTTTTT}
```

Problems I have stumbled upon and couldn't solve:

1. It should NOT recognizes this as a whole
   `${bbbbbbb}ccccccc${dddd}` but each for its own
2. grep -o is not installed on the old machine, Perl is not allowed either!
3. Many commands e.g. BASH_REMATCH only deliver the whole line or the first occurrence of the expression, instead of all matching expressions in the line!

The mentioned pattern `\${[^}]*}` seems to work partly, as it can extract the first occurrence of the expression, however it always omitts the ones following after that, if it's in the same text line. What I need is ALL matching expressions found in the line, not only the first one.

Comment: you need non-greedy match: [`perl -nE 'say $1 while /\${([^}]*)}/g'`](http://ideone.com/ZRsh6M)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it bugged me a lot I have asked directly on www.unix.com and was kindly provided with a solution which fits for my ancient shell. So if anyone got the same problem here is the solution:

```
line='aaaa$aa{yyy}aaa${important}xxxxxxxx${important2}oo{o$}oo$oo${importantstring3}'
IFS=\$ read -a words <<< "$line" 
regex='^(\{[^}]+})'
for e in "${words[@]}"; do
    if [[ $e =~ $regex ]]; then 
        echo "\$${BASH_REMATCH[0]}";
    fi;
done
```

which prints then the following - without even getting disturbed by random occurrences of `$` and `{` or `}` between the syntactically correct expressions:

```
${important}
${important2}
${importantstring3}
```

I have updated the full solution after I got another update from the forums: now it also ignores this: `aaa$aa{yyy}aaaa` - which it previously printed as ${yyy} - but which it should completely ignore as there are characters between `$` and `{`. Now with the additional anchoring on the beginning of the regexp it works as expected.

I just found another issue: theoretically using the above approach I would still get a wrong output if the read line looks like this `line='{ccc}aaaa${important}aaa'`. The IFS would split it and the REGEX would match `{ccc}` although this hadn't the `$` sign in front. This is suboptimal.
However following approach could solve it: after getting the BASH_REMATCH I would need to do a search in the original line - the one I gave to the IFS - for this exact expression `${ccc}` - with the difference, that the `$` is included! And only if it finds this exact match, only then, it counts as a valid match; otherwise it should be ignored. Kind of a reverse search method...

Updated - add this reverse search to ignore the trap on the beginning of the line:

```
pattern="\$${BASH_REMATCH[0]}";
searchresult="";
searchresult=`echo "$line" | grep "$pattern"`;

if [ "$searchresult" != "" ]; then echo "It was found!"; fi;
```

Neglectable issue: If the line looks like this `line='{ccc}aaaaaa${ccc}bbbbb'` it would recognize the *first* `{ccc}` as a valid match (although it isn't) and print it, because the reverse search found the *second* `${ccc}`. Although this is not intended it's irrelevant for my specific purpose as it implies that this pattern does in fact exist at least once in the same line.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string on any of the characters <kbd>$</kbd>,<kbd>{</kbd>,<kbd>}</kbd>:

```
$ s='...blaaaaa${blabla}bloooo${bla}bluuuuu...'
$ echo "$s"
...blaaaaa${blabla}bloooo${bla}bluuuuu...
$ IFS='${}' read -ra words <<< "$s"
$ for ((i=0; i<${#words[@]}; i++)); do printf "%d  %s\n" $i "${words[i]}"; done
0  ...blaaaaa
1  
2  blabla
3  bloooo
4  
5  bla
6  bluuuuu...
```

So if you're trying to extract the words inside the braces:

```
$ for ((i=2; i<${#words[@]}; i+=3)); do printf "%d  %s\n" $i "${words[i]}"; done
2  blabla
5  bla
```

---

If the above doesn't suit you, grep will work:

```
$ echo '...blaaaaa${blabla}bloooo${bla}bluuuuu...' | grep -o '\${[^}]\+}'
${blabla}
${bla}
```

You still haven't told us exactly what output you want.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but this won't work in this case as the whole expression "${...}" is required, and not only the word in between the brackets. With the IFS approach there is no way detecting the correct words after putting them into an array, because they have all removed their brackets or "separators". Maybe this was not clear enough in my post, sorry.

Comment: This second solution would be exactly what I need, if I had the "grep -o" option. Unfortunately I get "--o illegal option" and I must still find a way to get it done. Ridiculously enough most other commands only match against a whole line so, if I got 2 or more of these patterns in the same line, it will skip them and only display the first occurrence.